# 2 LAN cables connected, 1 PCI bus and vice versa

Tags: kernel, dmesg, pci

When booting my pc with 2 LAN cables connected only one interface is registered.

03:00.0 and 04:00.0

```
$ dmesg | grep -P '0(3|4):00.0'
[    0.180140] pci 0000:04:00.0: [11ab:4362] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.180181] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfa8fc000-0xfa8fffff 64bit]
[    0.180193] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xb800-0xb8ff]
[    0.180233] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfa8c0000-0xfa8dffff pref]
[    0.180277] pci 0000:04:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.180279] pci 0000:04:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.180337] pci 0000:04:00.0: disabling ASPM on pre-1.1 PCIe device.  You can enable it with 'pcie_aspm=force'
[    2.077454] sky2 0000:04:00.0: Yukon-2 EC chip revision 2
[    2.080310] sky2 0000:04:00.0 eth0: addr 00:00:00:00:66:b6
[    2.147949] sky2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[   18.815400] sky2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: enabling interface
[   21.829377] sky2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
```

When I boot the server with one cable both interfaces are found and can be used by plugging in the second cable.

```
$ dmesg | grep -P '0(3|4):00.0'
[    0.180140] pci 0000:04:00.0: [11ab:4362] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.180182] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfa8fc000-0xfa8fffff 64bit]
[    0.180193] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xb800-0xb8ff]
[    0.180233] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfa8c0000-0xfa8dffff pref]
[    0.180277] pci 0000:04:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.180280] pci 0000:04:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.180338] pci 0000:04:00.0: disabling ASPM on pre-1.1 PCIe device.  You can enable it with 'pcie_aspm=force'
[    0.180424] pci 0000:03:00.0: [11ab:4362] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.180465] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfa7fc000-0xfa7fffff 64bit]
[    0.180476] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xa800-0xa8ff]
[    0.180516] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfa7c0000-0xfa7dffff pref]
[    0.180559] pci 0000:03:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.180562] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.180620] pci 0000:03:00.0: disabling ASPM on pre-1.1 PCIe device.  You can enable it with 'pcie_aspm=force'
[    2.062437] sky2 0000:04:00.0: Yukon-2 EC chip revision 2
[    2.064723] sky2 0000:04:00.0 eth0: addr 00:00:00:00:66:b6
[    2.068332] sky2 0000:03:00.0: Yukon-2 EC chip revision 2
[    2.070348] sky2 0000:03:00.0 eth1: addr 00:00:00:00:62:84
[    2.140054] sky2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[    2.256554] sky2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth1
[   19.799013] sky2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: enabling interface
[   19.801113] sky2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: enabling interface
[   22.727625] sky2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[  412.644094] sky2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
```

What steps could I take to debug this further?

```
Extra info:
Motherboard: Asus P5W
Chipset: marvell Yukon 88E8053 
Drivers used(auto): sky2

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
Kernel: 4.4.0-138-generic
```

Edit 1:
I've compared the two dmesg logs and there are some interesting things:

When 1 cable is inserted:

```
Base memory trampoline at [        (ptrval)] 99000 size 24576
BRK [0x1a3d3f000, 0x1a3d3ffff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d40000, 0x1a3d40fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d41000, 0x1a3d41fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d42000, 0x1a3d42fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d43000, 0x1a3d43fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d44000, 0x1a3d44fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d45000, 0x1a3d45fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d46000, 0x1a3d46fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d47000, 0x1a3d47fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x1a3d48000, 0x1a3d48fff] PGTABLE
```

But when 2 cables are plugged in, there are less of these lines:

```
Base memory trampoline at [        (ptrval)] 99000 size 24576
BRK [0x0bd3f000, 0x0bd3ffff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x0bd40000, 0x0bd40fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x0bd41000, 0x0bd41fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x0bd42000, 0x0bd42fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x0bd43000, 0x0bd43fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x0bd44000, 0x0bd44fff] PGTABLE
BRK [0x0bd45000, 0x0bd45fff] PGTABLE
```

After that the only difference occurs when initilizing the PCI busses:

```
pci 0000:03:00.0: [11ab:4362] type 00 class 0x020000
pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfa7fc000-0xfa7fffff 64bit]
pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xa800-0xa8ff]
pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfa7c0000-0xfa7dffff pref]
pci 0000:03:00.0: supports D1 D2
pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
pci 0000:03:00.0: disabling ASPM on pre-1.1 PCIe device.  You can enable it with 'pcie_aspm=force'
pci 0000:00:1c.4: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
```

The rest is literally the same.

The more I'm looking into this, the more I think it's a hardware problem. Or maybe an option in the BIOS I'm unaware of and is not directly linked to LAN capabilities. The two ports do however perform normally when used with one cable, or two when one extra is inserted after boot.

Edit 2:
https://www.neoseeker.com/Articles/Hardware/Reviews/asus_p5wdh/3.html

I've added an external link with screenshots to the BIOS. I tried reading into all of them but could find anything regarding LAN except:

```
Onboard PCIE GbE LAN_1   **ENABLED**/DISABLED
Onboard PCIE GbE LAN_2   **ENABLED**/DISABLED
  LAN Option ROM         ENABLED/**DISABLED**
POST Check LAN Cable     **ENABLED**/DISABLED
```

I've played with these settings w/o result.

Comment: Did you ask your motherboard if it has some feature that may... abduct a NIC if found connected to a network on boot? Just guessing. But if you find no errors in `dmesg` it looks like the (integrated, right?) NIC is jealously guarded and not offered to the OS...

Comment: There is this option in the BIOS: 'LAN Option ROM', "Onboard PCIE GbE LAN Boot ROM Configuration". This was already disabled. It is indeed an integraded NIC.

Comment: I thought the shown behavior might have been related to some kind of port teaming (providing fault tolerance) by the motherboard, but searching for your hardware I can find no evidence of that. Sorry.

Comment: First step is to read through the *complete* `dmesg` of the error case, i.e. **not** using `grep`, and look for hints why `03:00.0` is disabled. As it's not enumerated in that case, grepping for it gets rid of all the information that is important. In general, **don't** grep if you are looking for reasons for unexplainable errors. Unfortunately, many people do this.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for your help. I've put the dmesg outputs side by side and added the differences in the question itself.

Comment: I'm also leaning towards "hardware problem". Does the 03:00.0 interface actually work (when booted unplugged)? Can you send packets over it?

Comment: Yes. I can use the interface when booted without a cable. It also works when  cable is in 03:00.0 and none in 04:00.0. So that's the strange part. They do work except when booted with two cables, then only 04:00.0 is found.